# Strange error in spring when adding thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i was working on a project using JSP then i thought about changing to thymeleaf instead, but when i did this is what i got

```
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Users\azza.a\Desktop\eclipse;;.
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:26 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CRUD' did not find a matching property.
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1029 ms
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [117] milliseconds.
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\azza.a\MGworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CRUD\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 26 12:17:30 AST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@c2ae54: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,studentController,studentDaoImpl,studentServiceImpl,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,templateResolver,templateEngine,org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2253 ms
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\azza.a\MGworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CRUD\]
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [C:\Users\azza.a\MGworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CRUD\WEB-INF\log4j.xml]
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Tue Nov 26 12:17:32 AST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ee43e2: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,studentController,studentDaoImpl,studentServiceImpl,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,templateResolver,templateEngine,org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@c2ae54
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Root mapping to handler [com.joseph.controller.StudentController@4bdeaa]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/student.do] onto handler [com.joseph.controller.StudentController@4bdeaa]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 247 ms
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5752 ms
Hibernate: select student0_.studentId as studentId2_, student0_.FirstName as FirstName2_, student0_.LastName as LastName2_, student0_.YearLevel as YearLevel2_ from STUDENT2 student0_
Nov 26, 2013 12:17:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/CRUD] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getRequestDataValueProcessor()Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestDataValueProcessor;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getRequestDataValueProcessor()Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestDataValueProcessor;
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.requestdata.RequestDataValueProcessor31Delegate.processAction(RequestDataValueProcessor31Delegate.java:51)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.requestdata.RequestDataValueProcessorUtils.processAction(RequestDataValueProcessorUtils.java:102)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.processor.attr.SpringActionAttrProcessor.getTargetAttributeValue(SpringActionAttrProcessor.java:72)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedAttributeValues(AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.java:61)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:973)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:928)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:947)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:947)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:947)
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i also made a spring-servelet.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.joseph" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>


<!--        <property name="configurationClass"> <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>  -->
<!--            </property> -->

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="MappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/Student.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Declare a Thymeleaf resolver -->
     <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/HTML/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" /> <!-- Development only -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine"
        p:templateResolver-ref="templateResolver" />

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
        p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine" />



    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

also a web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CRUD</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

before the change it was working fine but now i dont know what happend -_-"

Comment: Are you building with Maven and does thymeleaf have a transitive dependency to another (previous) version of spring perhaps?

Comment: no am not using maven ,and yeah i figured out that i was using thymeleaf 2.11 which is incompatible with spring 3.24